# How to do controlled rollout using Kubernetes deployment

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

We have 1000 store nodes and need to deploy an application image on every kubernetes node by rolling out in the below order and would like to specify the deployment node details during the deployment. Is there a way to specify node details in the command line when we execute kubectl create or apply deployment commands?

This application image would be configured to store/node specific details during container/POD creation.

1 node on day 1,
10 node on day 2,
100 node on day 3 etc.

Comment: I'd reckon this could be done with a `CI/CD` tools where you configure the logic behind the time of execution (each day) and by that you deploy your workload with increased replicas (1,10,100) with fields like `podAntiAffinity` and `topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"` (this would spawn a `Pod` on each `Node`). Have you seen [this documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/#affinity-and-anti-affinity) by any chance?

Answer (score 0):

Answering on the question from the title:

> How to do controlled rollout using Kubernetes deployment

You can create a `Deployment` that will have specific fields in its manifest that will configure the way Kubernetes handles it.

With the fields like: `podAntiAffinity`, `requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution` you can ensure that Kubernetes will distribute the `Pods` equally across the cluster `Nodes`. You can read more about it by following below documentation:

- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Scheduling eviction: Assign Pod to Node](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/scheduling-eviction/assign-pod-node/)*

Having in mind following rollout schedule:

| DAY | REPLICAS_COUNT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 10 |
| 3 | 100 |
| 4 | 1000 |

You could use `CI/CD` tools (like for example Jenkins) to rollout (change) the amount of replicas of your `Deployment` across a specific schedule.

You could create a Jenkins pipeline with a `deploy` stage where you could put your own command with it's scheduler (or delay).

The example of such `Deployment` that could be used with Jenkins is following:

```yaml
cat << EOF | kubectl apply -f -
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: ${REPLICAS_COUNT}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      affinity:
        podAntiAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
          - labelSelector:
              matchExpressions:
              - key: app
                operator: In
                values:
                - nginx
            topologyKey: "kubernetes.io/hostname"
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx
EOF
```

This `Deployment` will assign `Pods` to the `Nodes` that aren't already having an already running replica of this `Deployment` (i.e. 1 `Pod` = 1 `Node`). If the amount of `Pods` exceeds the amount of `Nodes` they will remain in `Pending` state.

---

Additional resources:

- *[Jenkins.io: Doc: Pipeline: Tour: Environment](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/environment/)*
- *[Kubernetes.io: Docs: Concepts: Workloads: Controllers: Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/)*